# How to custom HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length. on IIS

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, iis

> Help me custom HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length on IIS please

Answer (score 0):

IIS URL rewrite support custom response status and error description. You could create a rule to check the chunk header and http_content_length. If the request doesn't match chunked or have content length. Then URL rewrite module will return 411 error.

Comment: May I have a sequence of steps to do it?